# how user input can be one dimensional from multidimensional?

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

Abnormal behavior of `scanf()` function.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char c[100][100];
int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;++i) scanf("%s",c[i]+1);
}
```

my question is , since the we declare `c` as a `2` dimensional `array` , how can `scanf` take only one dimensional input , without any compilation `error`?

https://ideone.com/954oeO

is there some default value for the second parameter?

Comment: [Don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096#31816096).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What compilation error did you expect?

Comment: shouldn't scanf() take the argument in the form c[i][j] , like scanf("%s",c[i][j])                as we declared c as a 2dimensional char array

Comment: That would also compile, but it would be broken because `%s` expects a `char *`, not a `char`. It would probably end up crashing your program.

Comment: not actually the program didn't crashed ...

Comment: `c` is an array of 100 elements, each of which is `char[100]` - an array of 100 chars. `c[i]` refers to `i`th such array. An array name decays to a pointer to its first element, so `c[i]` can also be thought of as `&c[i][0]` - a pointer to the `0`th char of `i`th array. `c[i]+1` then points to the `1`st char of `i`th array. In other words, `c[i] + 1 == &c[i][1]`.

Comment: @nitinjain I said "probably". It's not guaranteed to crash (as always, broken C++ code can do anything it wants).

Comment: Igor Tandetnik , yes i ran the program and it gives the same ouput in both cases .

Comment: @melprone , the more clear explanation is given by igor above ... in both cases the ouput is same .. i think 2 dimensional arrays are not just like we think in the form of tables but its actually in the form of arrays inside arrays ... Thanks Igor Tandetnik for the explanation .

Comment: First, I'm not sure what you mean by "both cases"; I only see one piece of code. Second, I never claimed that this code wold fail to run. Third, the piece of code I see doesn't contain any statements that might produce output, so I don't see how it can produce any output, whether same or different.

Comment: @nitinjain C++ has no 2-dimensional arrays, only arrays of arrays.

Comment: Thanks Igor Tandetnik and melpomene for the help , now i understood it ...

Answer (score 1):

`c[i]` is the same as `&c[i][0]` due to array -> pointer conversion.
`c[i] + 1` is the same as `&c[i][1]`.

For that reason, use of

```
scanf("%s", c[i]+1);
```

is valid from a syntactic point of view.

However, keep in mind that if the input is too large to fit at the given location, you will run into the problem of accessing the array beyond the valid bounds. It will be better to use

```
scanf("%98s", c[i]+1);
```

There are 99 characters at `c[i]+1`. You need to have space for the terminating null character. Hence, the use of `%98s`.